# Nginx Url Rewrite Ineffective

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've the following path:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/restReport
```

And I need following rewrite:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/testReport
```

Tried this inside nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  logs/localhost.access.bear.log ;

        location = /user/restReport 
        { 
            rewrite ^/testReport?$ /restReport break;           
        } 
}
```

But the first get keeps pointing to its original path.
Tried different attemps based on this rewrite approach but nothing happened.

Comment: you need to rewrite restReport, in your rewrite you rewrite TESTreport.

Comment: already tried..won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  logs/localhost.access.bear.log ;

        location = /user/restReport 
        { 
            rewrite ^/restReport?$ /testReport break;           
        } 
 }
```

Comment: An explanation, what the posted code does and how this addresses the problem in the question, rarely fails to improve an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your location statement matches exactly one URI (i.e. `/user/restReport`).

Your rewrite statement matches exactly two URIs (i.e. `/testReport` and `/testRepor`).

As the rewrite statement is contained within the location statement, the rewrite will never see a matching URI.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: The regular expression `^/testReport?$` does not match the URI `/user/restReport` which is why the `rewrite` doesn't happen.